# MPMusicPlayer mute volume is not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4

Hi i have 2 audio player in a same single viewController class xib, both will play different songs simultaneously and both is having a individual mute buttons.when i click the mute button of one player it is muting iPods default volume control to mute so that i'm not able to here another players song which is not in mute condition. My code is as below

```
MPMusicPlayer *playerA;
MPMusicPlayer *playerB;
```

and

```
playerA = [MPMusicPlayer iPodMusicPlayer];
playerB = [MPMusicPlayer iPodMusicPlayer];
```

then inside my mute button function

```
playerA.volume = 0.0;//this line is not at all working
```

//so i replaced above line with

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:0.0];//but this will mute default iPod's (s/m) volume control
```

so how can i acheive this? Any help is helpful and thanks in advance.

Comment: It would surprise me if you're actually able to play different songs with `playerA` and `playerB` since both point to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pause one player.  `[playerA pause];`